# Python - the fastest, most efficient, simplest way to get consonants

Tags: python, string

I wrote pretty simple code which generate consonants. I wonder is this the best solution?

With best I mean: the fastest, most efficient, simplest way.

```
import string

letters = string.ascii_lowercase
vowels = 'aeiouy'
consonants = ''.join([letter for letter in letters if letter not in vowels])
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use a string literal of `bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz` ?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, only one. In my opinion it looks bad. But I could be wrong. That's why I ask.

Comment: If you're concerned about efficiency, then I would certainly just use `consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'`! It doesn't "look bad" in my opinion - and for people reading the code later, it's immediately obvious what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the most efficient way, I would just hardcode the values (Python will intern this string literal and won't have to calculate anything each time):

```
consonants = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
```

It's also the most readable for people reading the code later - it's very obvious what you're after.

Comment: @Ben: Does `y` letter is consonant? English isn't my native language, but... ;)

Comment: @MateuszJagiełło yes, it is a consonant - but it is one that often acts like a vowel ;-)

Comment: `y` can be both a consonant and a vowel, and if you look at the asked question, you'll see that it is requested that `y` be considered in this context a vowel.

Comment: Well, that's easy for the OP to change if he wants to. What is and isn't exactly a consonant wasn't really my point in this answer.

Comment: This is wrong place to discuss about letters, but it's interesting. In polish language `y` is vowel (which is explained by pronunciation). In english `y` could be vowel and consonant.